# How do I render a View in Durandal with data returned from a jsonp call?

Tags: javascript, api, jsonp, durandal

I'm having trouble viewing the data that is returned from a JSONP call to a restful api service. I'm using Durandal. I'm not sure if it's not rendering because I'm using the wrong data-binding or if it's because of the jsonp or if it's some other reason.

This is what I have in my clients.js file:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {
return {
        displayName: 'Clients',
        clients: ko.observableArray([]),
        activate: function () {
            var that = this;

            return http.jsonp('http://site/api/clients/1', 'jsoncallback').then(function (response) {
                that.clients(response.items);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

The data that is returned looks like this:

```
{
Id: 1,
Company: "Exosis",
email: "alisasandoval@exosis.com",
phone: "+1 (824) 431-2547",
address: "234 Ruby Street, Beechmont, Connecticut, 5450",
about: "Consectetur dolore excepteur ex sit nostrud.Voluptate tempor dolore minim do aliqua duis consequat nostrud amet. Nisi consequat eu Lorem ipsum.",
clientStartDate: "1990-09-18",
isActive: true,
clientType: "multiple"
}
```

What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to connect (data-bind) to the data being returned. I've tried all the variations I could think of. 
This is the clients.hmtl file:

```
<body> 
    <section>
        <h2 data-bind="text: displayName"></h2>
        <div data-bind="foreach: clients">
                <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: Company"> </div>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
```

Thanks for any feedback.

UPDATE
So I changed clients.js to
    that.clients.push(response.items);
And in the debugger I have
clients: Array[1]
0: undefined

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No error. Nothing appears.

Comment: Looks fine to me, though I would recommend downloading the chrome knockout context debugger which will help you see what you are binding to: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en

Comment: Does "Clients" show up in the displayName binding if you comment out the activate function?

Comment: Make sure the context of `this` is correct when `activate()` is called.

Comment: @ShaunRowan I have the knockout context debugger for chrome I just can't figure out how it works. What do you do after clicking the "enable tracing"?

Comment: The enable tracing area is not what you want.  What you want to do is select an element with the magnifying glass, then click "knockout context" in the "styles/Computed/Event Listeners/DOM breakpoints/Properties" menu area.

Comment: @ShaunRowan That works. =) And displayName does show up. There isn't anything to select for the clients loop.

Comment: Then maybe it's still an empty array?  Did you check your network tab to see what is being returned from the server?  Did you try setting a breakpoint in the data callback to see what's coming back?  What if you initialize clients as clients: ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Company: 'foo'}])  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can replace the array once it's initialized. Try `push`ing each element using [Knockout's pseudo-array functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) (not the native `push`).

You might want to wait for a confirmation, I can't test a replace immediately, but I'm positive pushing works as advertised.

Also test with local data first and monitor your network traffic after you re-enable the JSON-P functionality.

*And while I'm at it; consider CORS if you can (unrelated).*

Comment: Pushing helps. I'm still stuck with an array I can't seem to look at however. I wonder if it's because the jsonp data is wrapped in a clients class.